# Discord.py Ban all discord issue

Tags: discord

I created a ban all discord command by using a few tutorials on stack overflow but the problem is the bot attempts to ban itself and prioritizes that first, making the bot completely not work, any suggestions? Here's my code:

```
async def ban(ctx):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        try:
            await member.ban(reason="Banned")
            print(f"Banned {member.display_name}!")
        except:
            print(f"Could not ban {member.display_name}")
```

Comment: You should put a code that filters itself.

Comment: How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

```py
async def ban(ctx):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        if member.id == bot.user.id:
            continue
        try:
            await member.ban(reason="Banned")
            print(f"Banned {member.display_name}!")
        except:
            print(f"Could not ban {member.display_name}")
```

This code makes the bot continue the loop if the member is itself

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. I had to replace bot w/ client.user.id (on the tutorial I watched that's what they used), doesn't print any error just doesn't ban anyone from the server.

Comment: Did you check if the bot has enough permissions?

Comment: Yeah, I gave it all permissions including administrator privileges.

Comment: Is the bot's highest role is higher than the users?

Comment: I noticed that the guild is greyed out and says ""guild" is not accessed by Pylance", What does this mean?

Comment: And yes, it does have the highest role.

Comment: Do you have the intent required?